# Probability of not drawing a set of numbers from distribution

Tags: r, probability, distributions

I'm running a simulation where random variates are drawn from a negative binomial distribution, with size `s` and mean `mu`. I need to calculate the probability that I will **not** draw a value greater than value `x`, in `i` number of samples.

Should I calculate: If you draw `i` samples, the probability that one of the variates will be less than `x` is `p`. Then I can take `1-p`? If so, should I be using [these R functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/NegBinomial.html)?